# Show that $7^6 \equiv 2^7 \pmod{223}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given $7 \cdot2^5 \equiv 1\pmod{223}$. Show that $7^6 \equiv 2^7 \pmod{223}$.

I know there must be some clever way to show this congruence. I can't seem to figure it out. I've considered that $224=7\cdot2^5$ and tried multiplying both sides of the first congruence by various terms, but with little success. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Multiply both sides of $7 \cdot2^5 \equiv 1$ by $2^{222-5}$, then raise to the $6$th power. Use Fermat's theorem.

Comment: It seems to reduce to showing $2^{37}\equiv 1(mod 223)$. Which by Fermat's theorem means that $2$ is a sixth power, its easy to see $2\equiv 15^2 (mod 223)$, so it remains to see that $2$ is a cube, but I havent been able to find it.

Comment: Since $223-1= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 37$, there aren't many possibilities for the order of $2$ mod $223$.

Comment: $2\equiv 25^6 (\mod 223)$ and therefore $2^{37}\equiv 1 (\mod 223)$ the result follows.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: a way to avoid the “out of nowhere” $25^6$ is to note that $2$ is a cube iff $2^5$ is, iff $7$ is, iff $-7$ is, iff $6^3=-7+223$ is – QED.

Answer (score 3):

A not clever method?
$$
\begin{aligned} 7^6 &\equiv (7^3)^2 \\
                    &\equiv 343^2 \\
                    &\equiv 120^2 \\
                    &\equiv 240 \times 60 \\
                    &\equiv 17 \times 60 \\
                    &\equiv 60 + 4 * 4 * 60 \\
                    &\equiv 60 + 4 * 17 \\
                    &\equiv 128 \ ({\rm mod}\ 223)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score -2):

Starting from the congruence $7\cdot2^{5}\equiv1\pmod{223}$ perform equivalent transformations for obtaining the congruence $7^{6}\equiv2^{7}\pmod{223}$:

*(Really?—Cokoni's method is much better—be that as it may...)*

\begin{aligned}
7\cdot2^{5}&\equiv1&\pmod{223}
\end{aligned}

Multiply by $2^{222-5}$:

\begin{aligned}
7\cdot2^{5}\cdot2^{222−5}&\equiv1\cdot2^{222−5}\\
&\equiv2^{222−5}&\pmod{223}\\
\end{aligned}

Raise to the power of 6:

\begin{aligned}
(7\cdot2^{5}\cdot2^{222−5})^{6}&\equiv(2^{222−5})^{6}&\pmod{223}\\
(7\cdot2^{222})^{6}&\equiv(2^{222−5})^{6}&\pmod{223}\\
7^{6}\cdot(2^{222})^{6}&\equiv(2^{222−5})^{6}&\pmod{223}\\
7^{6}\cdot(2^{6})^{222}&\equiv(2^{222−5})^{6}&\pmod{223}
\end{aligned}

Fermat's "Little Theorem":
$a^{p}\equiv a\pmod{p}$ iff $p$ is a prime number.
$a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ iff $a\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$.
223 is a prime number which can form the value of $p$.

\begin{aligned}
7^{6}\cdot1&\equiv(2^{222−5})^{6}&\pmod{223}\\
7^{6}&\equiv(2^{217})^{6}\\
&\equiv(2^{31\cdot7})^{6}\\
&\equiv2^{31\cdot7\cdot6}\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot2^{31\cdot7\cdot6-7}&\pmod{223}
\end{aligned}

(From now on it is just simple power arithmetic for showing that $2^{31\cdot7\cdot6-7}\equiv1\pmod{223}$.)

\begin{aligned}
7^{6}&\equiv2^{7}\cdot2^{7\cdot(31\cdot6-1)}\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot2^{7\cdot185}\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot2^{1295}\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot2^{8\cdot161+7}\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot2^{8\cdot161}\cdot2^{7}\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot2^{8\cdot161}\cdot128\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot(2^{8})^{161}\cdot128\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot256^{161}\cdot128\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot33^{161}\cdot128\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot33^{160}\cdot33\cdot128\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot33^{160}\cdot4224\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot33^{160}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot(33^{2})^{80}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot1089^{80}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot197^{80}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot(197^{2})^{40}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot38809^{40}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot7^{40}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot7^{4\cdot10}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot(7^4)^{10}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot2401^{10}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot171^{10}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot(171^{2})^{5}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot29241^{5}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot28^{5}\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot28^{4}\cdot28\cdot210\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot28^{4}\cdot5880\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot28^{4}\cdot82\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot(28^{2})^{2}\cdot82\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot784^{2}\cdot82\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot115^{2}\cdot82\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot115\cdot115\cdot82\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot115\cdot9430\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot115\cdot64\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot7360\\
&\equiv2^{7}\cdot1\\
&\equiv2^{7}&\pmod{223}
\end{aligned}

---

---

\begin{aligned}
7\cdot2^{5}&\equiv1\pmod{223}
\end{aligned}
Multiply by $7^5$:
\begin{aligned}
7^{6}\cdot2^{5}&\equiv7^{5}\pmod{223}\\
\end{aligned}
Subtract $7^{6}\cdot(2^{5}-1)$ and convert to sum product with factor 223 and summand 128:
\begin{aligned}
7^{6}&\equiv7^{5}-7^{6}\cdot(2^{5}-1)\equiv-3630312\equiv-16280\cdot223+128\equiv128\equiv2^{7}\pmod{223}
\end{aligned}